# Vaadin session scaling

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, vaadin, session-state

Anyone can suggest a solution to store sessions created in Vaadin in order to make a application fault tolerant?

Can sessions be stored in Redis or Memcached?

The idea is to run an large scale application (Vaadin + Spring) using only SPOT instances in AWS!

Comment: Hello, maybe this plugin could help you : https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/spring-session-redis